# Setting input fields touched equal false in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have `redux-form` where I have input field when it is touched it shows error if there are any. Now I want reset the input fields touched property to `false` when page is reloaded . how do I do it?

I am using `redux-persist` to persist state so I have to explicitly do this so I need a way set touched property to false in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Have you tried action creators? https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-touch-form-string-fields-string-code-

Comment: nope how do I use it Im newbie to redux-form

Comment: I think I want to use untouch in componentDidMount

Comment: should I use it like this this.props.untouch('formName', 'fieldName')

Comment: Yes I got it I have to use it the above way

Comment: write in the answer block ill accept your answer

Comment: Add answer. Thanks OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't touched `redux-form` for a while, so please bear with any problem in my sample code.

Redux-form's action creators can be used normally as dispatcher. You just need to import the action and use it in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
import { untouch } from 'redux-form/actions'

...
componentDidMount() {
    const fieldArray = getFields() // your own methods
    this.props.untouch(fieldArray)
}

...

const mapStateToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    untouch: (fieldArray) => dispatch(untouch("YOUR_FORM_NAME", fieldArray))
})
```